# Como modifico uma url com o .htacess?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

Tenho a url exemplo.com/foto gostaria de modificá-la para exemplo.com/imagem

Observação tenho o acesso ao .htacess e aos modulos apache.

Answer (score 2):

Este artigo pode te ajudar [URL Rewriting for Beginners](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/).

Usando o que é mostrado no artigo acredito que o seguinte código possa ser aplicado.

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
# Manda requisições com endereço de imagem para "foto.php" onde foto.php é o arquivo que 
# irá processar as requisições.
# NC informa ao apache que é case insensitive e L diz que caso esta regra seja usada as 
# demais não devem ser usadas.
RewriteRule    ^imagem/?$    foto.php    [NC,L]
```

Ainda segundo este outro artigo [Redirecting a Web Folder Directory to another Directory in htaccess](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/redirecting-a-web-folder-directory-to-another-in-htaccess/) o código poderia ser:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule ^imagem/(.*)$ /foto/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

O `R=301` informa que a requisição deve retornar o código 301 para informar que houve um redirecionamento, o `NC` e o `L` funcionam da mesma forma que o anterior. O `$1` é Expressão regular básica e representa a captura do primeiro grupo de captura da expressão regular, neste caso o `(.*)$` que basicamente é tudo o que for inserido depois do imagem.

Tente mudar o seu arquivo adicionando esta linha e se assegurando que não há nenhuma regra antes desta que seja ativada antes e possua a diretiva `L`, que faria com que esta não fosse mais ativada.

Espero que isso ajude.